# How to zoom in and out in fl_chart flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, fl-chart

I am using fl_chart library for line chart, but there is no option for zoom in out chart, how to zoom fl line chart?

Comment: You already had answer on github for your post : https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/issues/1082

Comment: but that is not working it only increasing x and y axis value